# I need support on the API I specified on Instagram

Tags: instagram

I get the following information as json from the api I use here, but I encountered a new problem, while previously there was a limit of 15000, now the account is being spammed in a transaction like 2000, I'm looking for a solution to this by Instagram, I'd be glad if someone writes with the information

Also, if I can get the following features from somewhere else, there will be a room, does anyone have information about where else I can shoot

Features I have taken as the data I am looking for:

['user']['pk'];

['user']['username'];

['user']['full_name'];

['user']['is_verified'];

['user']['profile_pic_url'];

['user']['public_email'];

['user']['follower_count'];

['user']['gating']['title'];

['user']['biography'];

The Instagram api I use:

https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/userid/info/

i tried to use a proxy and increase the limit, but the limit did not increase again, when 2000 transactions are made, it becomes spam the account was previously making 15000 transactions without a proxy